# Analytical solution to this second order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find an analytical solution to the following equation:

$$a_1 x''(t)+a_2x'(t)+a_3x(t)^\alpha+a_4t+a_5=0$$

where $0<\alpha<1$. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's unlikely to have closed-form general solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you **some** solutions in the case $\alpha = 1/2$.  Namely, in this case 
$x(t) = (b_1 t + b_0)^2$  is a solution when $b_1$ is a root of the quadratic
$$ 2 a_2 b_1^2 + a_3 b_1 + a_4 = 0$$ and $$b_0 = -{\frac {2\,{a_1}\,{{ b_1}}^{2}+{ a_5}}{2\,{ a_2}\,{ b_1}+{
 a_3}}}$$
and $b_1 t + b_0 > 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think of there are other solutions in the case $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, of course there are other solutions by the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.  But there might not be other closed-form solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Would there be some value of $0<\alpha<1$ for which closed-formed general solutions can be obtained?

Comment: I doubt it very much.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you, your comments have been very helpful. I have another question for you if you don't mind. This differential equation is the HJB equation for a dynamic programming problem that I'm working on. For this dynamic problem, I need to at least be able to show that there exists a unique $t^\ast$ such that $x(t^\ast)=f(t^\ast)$ and $x'(t^\ast)=f'(t^\ast)$ where $f(t)$ is some given function (these are value matching and smooth pasting conditions). Do you have any references related to this?

Comment: Of course you can't do that in general.  What if $f = x$? What if $f = x + 1$?